# Why is the lookup for T in this code successful?

Tags: c++, scope, language-lawyer, name-lookup

The lookup for `T` should fail

```
class A
{
    typedef int T;
    void f(void)
    {
        class B {};
        class C
        {
            class D : public B
            {
                void g(void)
                {
                    T a;
                }
            };
        };
    }
};
```

because 3.4.1 paragraph 8 from N4567 says that

> For the members of a class `X`, a name used **in a member function body**,
>   in a default argument, in an *exception-specification*, in the
>   *brace-or-equal-initializer* of a non-static data member (9.2), or in the definition of a class member outside of the definition of `X`,
>   following the member’s *declarator-id*, shall be declared in one of
>   the following ways:
>
> - before its use in the block in which it is used or in an enclosing block (6.3), or
> - shall be a member of class `X` or be a member of a base class of `X` (10.2), or
> - if `X` is a nested class of class `Y` (9.7), shall be a member of `Y`, or shall be a member of a base class of `Y` (this lookup applies in turn to
>     `Y`’s enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class),
>     or
> - if `X` is a local class (9.8) or is a nested class of a local class, before the definition of class `X` in a block enclosing the definition
>     of class `X`, or
> - **if `X` is a member of namespace `N`, or is a nested class of a class that is a member of `N`, or is a local class or a nested class within a
>     local class of a function that is a member of `N`, before the use of the
>     name, in namespace `N` or in one of `N`’s enclosing namespaces.**

To be more specific, the lookup for `T` is done as the following:

1. before `T`'s use in `g`
2. shall be a member of class `D` or be a member of class `B`
3. shall be a member of class `C`
4. before the definition of class `D` in `f`
5. **???**

The problem is that `D` is not

- a member of a namespace,
- a nested class of a class that is a member of a namespace,
- a local class,
- a nested class within a local class of a function that is a member of a namespace,

but rather **a nested class within a local class of a function that is a member of a class**.

Comment: See [CWG 191](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#191).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a problem with the way the name lookup rules were specified in the standard until very recently.

We all know what the order should be: the block scope of `g`, then the scopes of enclosing entities, starting with the innermost enclosing entity. That is, `D`, then `C`, then `f`, then `A`, then the global namespace. But if any of these entities is a class, then its base classes are searched after it and before the next enclosing entity. But the wording did not do a good job of describing it. As pointed out in the comments, this issue was [CWG 191](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/191.html), which was only resolved recently by "Declarations and were to find them". The new and improved wording will be in C++23. Let's take a look at what the draft says...

Clearly the name lookup for `T` in this case is unqualified name lookup, so let's start there. Unqualified name lookup performs an *unqualified search* ([[basic.lookup.unqual]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#3)) in its *immediate scope* (which is defined elsewhere; suffice it to say that it's the block scope of `g`).

An unqualified search of the block scope of `g` performs a *search* in that scope. It would also search other scopes if any *using-directives* were active, which is not the case in your example. Finally, if the search finds nothing, then it searches the parent scope of whatever scope was being searched ([[basic.lookup.unqual]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#2)). Thus, the block scope of `g` will be searched first, then `D`, then `C`, then `f`, then `A`, then the global namespace.

A *search* is defined in [[class.member.lookup]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.member.lookup#1). When the scope being searched is not a class scope, it's just a *single search*. When it is a class scope, a complicated algorithm is used to perform a single search in that class first; then, if nothing is found, it goes to the base classes.

So `g` is single-searched first, then `D`, then `B`, then `C`, then `f`, then `A`, then the global namespace.

A *single search* in a given scope is defined in [[basic.lookup.general]/3](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.general#3). It finds declarations that *bind* the name being searched for to that scope, and that precede the point where the name lookup occurs. In the example, the declaration `typedef int T;` binds the name `T` in the class scope of `A`.